# After cocoapods installation code crashes on library

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods, xcode8

SO I was doing fine by using [FSPagerView](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView) when I was not using Cocoapods but when I installed Cocoapods and removed the previous (**FSPagerView**) files from the project, the code comes to an infamous "class not key-value complaint" crash without much information. The crash logs are as follows:

```
Unknown class _TtC14MyApp11FSPagerView in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class _TtC14MyApp13FSPageControl in Interface Builder file.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7fce69f03010> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dataSource.'
```

What am I doing wrong? I would really like to know and get going. Appreciate your help, whatever you can give :)

P.S. I am using workspace instead of project, my delegate and datasource link are appropriately handled but I am still certain it has some Interface Builder BS!

Answer (score 0):

According to the error description your IB file has a wrong class name associated with some view. Most likely it is because you have to use a "Namespace.ClassName" format here since CocoaPods have their own namespaces. By default namespace is the same as a pod name.

Open your IB file, find required view and check that it's class name is "FSPagerView.FSPagerView". For FSPageControl element class name should be "FSPagerView.FSPageControl".

Comment: Still no luck man, whenever I enter in the Custom Class it goes back to the same and crashes just like before :(

Answer (score 0):

So it isn't really an Interface Build problem, rather Xcode's with Cocoapods. Basically **Cocoapods** don't automatically include frameworks into the Linking Frameworks when

```
pod install
```

is executed. Rather you have to go into

```
Target > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries
```

and then add them there. This solved the problem. Pretty easy eh?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen with a UIViewController subclass and the solution was to tick 'Inherit from Target' where I set the Custom Class in IB.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the class was not part of the Target Membership. Just add the class to the target, and you should see it back on the interface builder.

[image]